# Not meeting the min. GRE requirement

Tags: graduate-admissions

If I do not meet the min. GRE score requirement, shall I apply to the school anyway?

Answer (score 7):

No. It's a waste of your money, and a waste of their time. Your application will simply be filtered out.

There are cases where schools make exceptions. But they need to know that they should make an exception and why -- so if you think that you have a particularly good reason why you do not meet their minimal threshold, write an email to the graduate adviser of the chair of the graduate committee and tell them about it.